# Mongodb Huge Number of Open Connections and Write Locks

Tags: mongodb, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

We are seeing around 800 open connections to our Mongodb. To clarify our issue:

1. We have 5 different clients who write the data into Mongodb. Each of these clients - write four different type of documents into their respective collections. And they have 25 goroutines each. So in total at anytime there could be around 100 goroutines from each of these clients. Due to high load, we see that 500 connections from these clients are opened (we confirmed this by stopping all these clients and the connection count reduces)
2. We have 3 different servers, which read the Mongodb primary. And these are serving different requests. And these have around 40 connections open.

The remaining 260 connections (800 - (500+40)), seems to be leaks. We are trying to reproduce the issue here.

In total, we have around 800 connections opens.

Due to this huge opened connections, we see that normal queries take around 10 seconds! But when we stop the 5 clients, the response of these queries are served between 400-800 ms.

I have already verified using `explain` and all these queries are served on Index only .

Any tips on debugging/handling this issue.

Note: My guess is, due to huge number of writes, the mongodb is constantly busy and not able to process the query. We have primary and a secondary. But currently we are always reading only from the primary. Any tips here would also be good.

We are using mongodb 3.0 with MMAPv1. We are planning to move to wiredTiger.

**Update1:**

All the details of the mongo data, cpu, etc.

We have two DB within mongo

```
DB1  17.945GB
DB2  17.945GB
```

DB1 Stats in GB

```
rs1:PRIMARY> db.stats(1024*1024*1024)
{
    "db" : "DB1",
    "collections" : 15,
    "objects" : 4171674,
    "avgObjSize" : 2214.681749340912,
    "dataSize" : 8.604424327611923,
    "storageSize" : 13.75045008957386,
    "numExtents" : 138,
    "indexes" : 34,
    "indexSize" : 1.5781951248645782,
    "fileSize" : 17.9296875,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "extentFreeList" : {
        "num" : 0,
        "totalSize" : 0
    },
    "dataFileVersion" : {
        "major" : 4,
        "minor" : 22
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

DB2 Stats in GB

```
rs1:PRIMARY> db.stats(1024*1024*1024)
{
    "db" : "DB2",
    "collections" : 36,
    "objects" : 2383787,
    "avgObjSize" : 6308.773688253187,
    "dataSize" : 14.005948513746262,
    "storageSize" : 16.816604614257812,
    "numExtents" : 315,
    "indexes" : 70,
    "indexSize" : 0.6485644727945328,
    "fileSize" : 17.9296875,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "extentFreeList" : {
        "num" : 0,
        "totalSize" : 0
    },
    "dataFileVersion" : {
        "major" : 4,
        "minor" : 22
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Currently, we have reduced our 5 clients to each have only 60 connections each. So the current `mongostat` of our server looks like:

```
insert query update delete getmore command flushes mapped vsize  res faults idx miss % qr|qw ar|aw netIn netOut conn set repl     time
    *0     2      4     *0       0    12|0       0  40.1G 83.3G 5.7G      0          0 1|189 1|189    2k    13k  279 rs1  PRI 17:22:59
    *0    *0      3     *0       0    16|0       0  40.1G 83.3G 5.7G      0          0 1|192 1|192    1k    13k  279 rs1  PRI 17:23:00
     8     3    812     *0      64    60|0       0  40.1G 83.3G 5.7G      1          0 1|190 1|203  702k   458k  279 rs1  PRI 17:23:05
     1     1    208     *0      49   103|0       0  40.1G 83.3G 5.6G      1          0 1|193 1|213  217k   134k  280 rs1  PRI 17:23:08
    44     2   2030     *0     218    82|0       0  40.1G 83.3G 5.7G      4          0 1|209 2|211    2m     1m  280 rs1  PRI 17:23:09
     1    *0     96     *0      12    15|0       0  40.1G 83.3G 5.7G      1          0 1|211 1|211   77k    71k  280 rs1  PRI 17:23:10
    10     1   1057     *0     116    98|0       0  40.1G 83.3G 5.7G      0          0 1|209 2|215  941k   609k  280 rs1  PRI 17:23:13
    *0     2     26     *0       6    35|0       0  40.1G 83.3G 5.7G      2          0 3|217 3|217   26k    43k  280 rs1  PRI 17:23:14
    *0    *0      1     *0       0    12|0       0  40.1G 83.3G 5.7G      0          0 3|218 3|218    1k    13k  280 rs1  PRI 17:23:15
    *0     1      2     *0       0    12|0       0  40.1G 83.3G 5.7G      0          0 3|220 3|220    1k    12k  280 rs1  PRI 17:23:16
insert query update delete getmore command flushes mapped vsize  res faults idx miss % qr|qw ar|aw netIn netOut conn set repl     time
    *0    *0     *0     *0       0    11|0       0  40.1G 83.3G 5.7G      0          0 3|220 3|220  806b    12k  280 rs1  PRI 17:23:17
     4     1    660     *0      64    28|0       1  40.1G 83.3G 5.7G      1          0 1|219 2|221  583k   394k  280 rs1  PRI 17:23:19
    28     5   1775     *0     148    34|0       0  40.1G 83.3G 5.7G      5          0 0|200 0|207    2m     1m  280 rs1  PRI 17:23:20
     1     1    429     *0      10    11|0       0  40.1G 83.3G 5.7G      5          0 0|189 0|189  420k   309k  280 rs1  PRI 17:23:21
```

Notice the conn count => **280**.

At this time, the `top` output looks like

```
top - 17:24:01 up 6 days,  3:07,  1 user,  load average: 8.55, 6.31, 5.96
Tasks:  94 total,   1 running,  93 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  5.3 us,  2.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 91.8 id,  0.7 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   8176828 total,  8042296 used,   134532 free,   121640 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.  6569776 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 2039 root      20   0 83.338g 5.714g 4.795g S  28.2 73.3   6233:19 mongod
 5741 root      20   0       0      0      0 D   1.0  0.0  21:23.15 kworker/u8:0
 1035 deploy    20   0  425500  11724   4728 S   0.3  0.1  50:39.10 consul
    1 root      20   0   33504   2472   1120 S   0.0  0.0   0:11.16 init
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.10 kthreadd
```

We do notice that the **`Cached` memory has reached to almost 8GB of the total RAM.** How to handle this is the question here.

Regarding the `explain`, what we see is, when we call the `explain` sometimes that itself takes 2-3 seconds to respond. This only means that mongodb is not responding (ie, we are not able to open the session at this time or we are connected, but has not yet started the processing).

Just by stopping our clients, we close the session, and then mongodb is **lightning fast**.

Comment: That's odd.  What is your total database + index size, what is the total available RAM, and what do your performance metrics show re: memory/cpu/diskio/hard faults?  If your hypothesis is correct, the question would be 'why'?  Almost always a MongoDB performance issue is indexing.  Is it indexed AND sorted?  That's critical.  Please share your explain.pretty() output if you can as well.  Thanks.

Comment: @AliRazeghi I have updated the question. See `Update 1`. Please let me know, if you have any other questions

Comment: Your problem doesn't seem to be the high numbers of connections but the high number of concurrent updates. From the mongostat i guess you use MMap that uses collection level locking. If under normal load an update takes 400-800 ms then its normal under high write to get poor performance, since your updates are queuing waiting to be served. WT will help and sharding will also increase the write scope. Can you share the updates you are running and the explain for these updates.

Comment: @Antonios Thanks for the info. WT will be done over the weekend. Sharding - we will check it. How to get `explain` for updates. At least using `mgo` the go library, it seems not possible to get `explain` on Update. WRT update: We collect performance data from browsers, and we have indeed a huge number of write calls. So it definitely is write intensive. One question would be - even if we read from Secondary in this case, it would result in the same situation - is that correct? Because, secondary is constantly syncing with the primary. Is there a way to allow read as higher priority?

Comment: Use the query part of the update to run an explain. The query part of the update should always use an index.  Read from the SEC won't help much as primary CRUD operations will also execute on the secondaries.

Comment: @Antonios I use UpsertId call in mgo, which means, I run using `_id`, which is always indexed. One thought we are having now is that, probably our writes are constantly moving the documents around - which may be delaying as well. Note: We have around 130 hits per second, which means, we do either update or insert 130 times per second. How to find if our documents are being reallocated constantly. Any tips there. Any other things that could be an issue here

Comment: According to the mongostat you perform more updates than inserts. To check if an update case document moves you need to check the nmoved property on the profiler collection. In order a document move occur the update need to increase the document size in a size bigger than the closer powerof2. In my opinion its just write congestion and you should look for sharding or WT (or both)

Comment: @Antonios Thanks. We indeed were doing too many updates. Currently we are planning to limit the updates. However, these updates were only incrementing counters. Meanwhile, we were doing a set of inserts, that was inserting huge documents. We have now ratelimited that inserts, and our performance has vastly improved. We are now moving to WT as well. We will check on sharding part. Thanks for all the tips. It helped us look into the right direction.

Comment: Great, i would be interested to know about the performance when you deploy WT

Comment: I doubt that it is a issue with mmapv1, let alone the problems being solved with a switch to WT. While the CPU load is rather low, we have a lot of pending IO. The bottleneck seems to be the disk IO. My bet would be spinning disks are used. RAID10 or SSDs often prevent the need to shard and vastly improve performance .

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg We are using it on SSDs. We have a huge number of updates coming through - in the range of 150 per second

Comment: @Sundar To be honest with you, that's not even a lot, neither the amount of connections nor from the update operations/s. In one of the clusters I manage, which I would call smallish to lower end medium size, ***each*** of the shards has 300+ connections, 4-500 updates/s (plus queries plus getmores), producing some 60GB oplog/h in peak, and it deals with that rather easily. From what I can see, there are processes waiting for IO. If it isn't the SSD (we are not talking of a VM, do we?), my next bet goes on insufficient RAM – a sustained utilization of 90%+ is a good indicator for that.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg We are running it on a VM from DigitalOcean. We are running with 4Core and 8GB RAM. Do you think a Dedicate Hardware would make a huge difference in this case? Also we see that the cached memory is constantly increasing in the mongodb and is lingering at 80-90%. In your case, could you please share the CPU, RAM and its usage, just to know what to expect. Also do you do preallocate of records, to avoid movements?

Comment: MongoDB does not need much CPU, so I'd probably reduce that and increase RAM. Dedicated hardware will indeed make a difference, since with VMs, IO is shared *by definition*. You want RAM utilization slightly less than 85%, issuing warnings when this line is crossed and an escalation level of 90%. As per the cluster I was talking of: no, I could not disclose any more information. And it would not help you, either, since every application has different needs.